# Why glTexSubImage2D is so slow?

Tags: performance, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to measure performance of glTexSubImage2D().
I need periodically update my texture 1920x1080 before rendering.
Strange is that sometimes glTexSubImage2D() takes less then 20ms but sometimes it takes up to 190ms.
Fragment of my measure log is:
22,
94,
21,
94,
22,
93,
22,
94,
36,
24,
98,
21,
94,
108,
121,
30,

Those above are milliseconds consumed by glTexSubImage2D() when full RGBA Texture is updated.
It is clear that I cannot use this for real time video rendering..

I do my experiments on embedded OpenGLES2 ROCK64 ARM board with Mali450  GPU enabled.

On Raspberry PI3 OpenGLES2 is specific but also glTexSubImage2D is not very fast. So question why it so slow? Is it possible to update texture somehow different way and faster?

Comment: Do you have the data you need to upload a few frames *before* you upload it?

Comment: Have you tried double buffering? Use two different textures and modify the one that hasn't been used by any draw calls for awhile.

Comment: Actually I found that saying "glTexSubImage2D" is slow not very correct. After updating texture I do calls for rendering like glDrawElements and eglSwapBuffers etc.. Those functions together take NO time from CPU, they are "very fast" for CPU, but next time glTexSubImage2d called it is blocked probably until frame is render complete. So I consider it as a queue of commands: glDrawElements just is queued but any next call to GLES probably stay in queue until rendering completes. So now my question is why actual rendering is so slow that blocks next glTexSubinage2D?

Answer (score 1):

That's typical that the OpenGL stalls the CPU when the frame is being rendered with the texture you're trying to udpate.

And a typical solution is to use a pair of textures. While GPU is busy with rendering from texture1, you update texture2 with data for the next frame. When the frame is done, you swap textures, so GPU is locking texture2, and you update texture1 meanwhile.